# CUDA + Visual Studio = suppressed output window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

Normally, when I use Visual Studio to do a build, I see warnings and errors shown in the output pane, e.g.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: pdcuda, Configuration: Release x64 ------
Compiling...
foo.cpp
Linking...
foo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "foo"
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm doing some GPU programming with [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html).  Upon upgrading to 2.1, I no longer get any useful output in Visual Studio.  For example, all I now see is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: pdcuda, Configuration: Release x64 ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The other details can be found in BuildLog.htm, but it's inconvenient to hunt that file down all the time.

Does anyone know how to force Visual Studio to show the output in its output pane?

Things that don't help:

- *uninstalling CUDA:* the problem persists in all projects
- *Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity:* changing this pulldown, even to "Diagnostic" has no discernable effect.

**EDIT:** Additional things that don't help:

- devenv.exe /resetsettings
- devenv.exe /resetuserdata

**UPDATE** *(in response to Die in Sente)*: It's now working on one of the two machines (I'm not sure what I did to fix it though).  The machine that's still having problems has a [CUDA Visual Studio Wizard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudavswizard) installed that has caused similar problems before.  The still-broken machine had version 15.00.21022.8 of the compiler.  The working machine has 15.00.30729.1.  After making a backup, I transferred "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64" from the working to the broken machine.  I observe no changes in behavior on the broken machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution: reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem, but without CUDA.  Today Visual Studio just decided it wasn't going to show any build messages anymore.  It was working fine, then one of my builds it just stopped working.  The problem persists over all my projects now, and persists over reboots.  I also see the correct messages in buildlog.htm.  This is ridonkulous!

EDIT: Ooh, I used the add/remove programs to do a repair, and now it works again!  Yeah!

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to reset IDE
devenv.exe /resetsettings
or
devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Answer (score 0):

I also recently install CUDA 2.1 (on top of 2.0 I believe). The default installation for CUDA 2.1 moved the SDK from

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA CUDA SDK\

to

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\NVIDIA Corportation\NVIDIA CUDA SDK\

which initially caused me some problems. Are all of your paths resolving correctly?

Comment: I've able to resolve the paths correctly.  Oddly, it's installed in the hidden directory tree C:\ProgramData for me.  When I fix the bugs and linker issues in my program, I can get it to build.  I just don't see any build messages like nvcc results, warnings, errors, etc.

Comment: I thought perhaps Visual Studio was having trouble locating nvcc and not being descriptive about it.

The BuildLog.htm contains all the errors that normally would be displayed in the output? What does your .cu build rule look like?

Comment: Yes, the BuildLog.htm contains all the errors and warnings that would have normally been displayed.  If I fix the errors, the build works (but the IDE output is still suppressed).  The build rule shows up as "CUDA Build Rule v2.1.0".  Its command line contains nothing surprising.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a far out suggestion. Get the CUDA SDK and try your code with the sample CUDA-C++ project in there. Maybe something changed in the build rules for CUDA v2.1.

Comment: Good idea.  Unfortunately, running the cppIntegration sample does not restore the IDE output.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run.  Last property is "MSBuild Project build output verbosity".  It defaults to Minimal, change it to normal and the build messages will show up in Output window.

This also enables any `<Message Text="test message"></Message>` output to show up in Visual Studio Build Output Window.